# Extrapolation from data set in a non-rectangular domain?

Tags: extrapolation

I have this set of data which can be regularly spaced if needed. The problem is that there are different regimes and the boundaries are non-rectangular.

For example, there is a change of phase that happens at the y = 1 - 1/x, meaning that the data behaves differently above and below this graph. I can sample the data everywhere, but I would like the extrapolation to be different above and below this line, as there would be problems extrapolating along the boundary.

At the moment, I can only think of cutting the spaces in rectangles, but that seems a bit complicated to do.

If anyone has any ideas of how I could do it best, that would be great ^^.

Thanks!